# Converting .deb package dependencies to a graphviz .dot graph using awk

Tags: awk, graphviz

I'm trying to write a convert.awk program that outputs a valid .dot graph using graphviz like this:

`$ awk –f convert.awk deb-9-packages.deb > output.dot`

So far I have no idea how to do it

.deb file format sample:

```
Package: libghc-temporary-dev
Source: haskell-temporary (1.2.0.4-3)
Version: 1.2.0.4-3+b1
Installed-Size: 145
Maintainer: Debian Haskell Group <pkg-haskell-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Provides: libghc-temporary-dev-1.2.0.4-c3ae9
Depends: libghc-base-dev-4.9.0.0-1bac3, libghc-directory-dev-1.2.6.2-a2e35, libghc-exceptions-dev-0.8.3-7b68b, libghc-filepath-dev-1.4.1.0-99c7a, libghc-transformers-dev-0.5.2.0-cdb38, libghc-unix-dev-2.7.2.0-8480b, libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~), libgmp10
Suggests: libghc-temporary-doc, libghc-temporary-prof
Description: Temporary files and directories
Homepage: http://www.github.com/feuerbach/temporary
Description-md5: b717775f10f14d831ace456e90acb20a
Ghc-Package: temporary-1.2.0.4-2l1bIkqO41RI46P32T9qrM
Tag: devel::lang:haskell
Section: haskell
Priority: extra
Filename: pool/main/h/haskell-temporary/libghc-temporary-dev_1.2.0.4-3+b1_i386.deb
Size: 26632
MD5sum: 9e6086986b910b1356a032bebf06c401
SHA256: d1ebb9b1851ae95f02f97671a82dca92eaca8dd4699bd52d39191208606a0caa

Package: libghc-temporary-doc
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for adding your efforts in form of code in your question. But your question is not clear,could you please do add more details(like logic of achieving your expected output etc) in your question and let us know.

Comment: Thank you, my main goal is to list the dependencies of "deb-9-packages.deb" in a valid graph format, hence trying to convert it into an "output.dot" file that can be readable. In the .deb file all dependencies for a package are described. I'm very new to awk so having a hard time knowing how to achieve this.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can post what the input file format is (a small yet representative sample will work best) and expected output for the input.

Comment: Added the format sample.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the real format of a .deb file, but it is the output of **less**  If you **cat** your .deb or try to edit it you will see something very different.  That said, **less** does produce that nice output, so:

```
less yourDebFile.deb | 
gawk -F":" '
$1==" Package"{pkg=$2;sub(/^ /,"",pkg)}
$1==" Depends"{
  cnt=split($2,dep,",")
  for(i=1;i<=cnt;i++){
    sub(/^ /,"",dep[i])
    print pkg, "->", "\"" dep[i] "\""
  }
}'
```